# Unable to compile class for JSP error?

Tags: java, jsp

i want to use the Java program in JSP.

i have  created java program Helloworld under package sam.jni

then in JSP program i called the Java class file using

```
<@ page import="sam.jni.Helloworld">
```

after deploying the JSP file i am getting unable to compile class for JSP error

where am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you provide the specific error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't that be

```
<%@ page import="sam.jni.Helloworld" %>
```

?